# Would this be a good hardware setup for Monero mining?

Tags: mining, gpu-mining, cryptonight, mining-hardware, hardware

I'm completely new to mining Monero but I want to give it a try and get more knowledge of hardware. So I got a good price for an Asrock D1800M. It is a BGA Celeron and the system should use around 20W without GPUs.

- Is this CPU enough to power up to three AMD RX 480 GPU?
- Is PCIe x1 enough for mining with GPUs?
- And what power does an RX 480 use while mining?

Thank you very much for reading this and big thanks for every answer!

Comment: Please see guidelines for questions here: http://monero.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 4):

GPU mining configurations often use the cheapest CPU. Thus, your CPU should be powerful enough to work with 3 Rx 480.  Yes, PCIE x 1 should work for mining but you have to buy a riser (recommended to use a powered riser).  RX 480 draws around 150W (from specification) - 200W. Probably give some more allowance when buying your Power Supply and don't go cheap on it.

Lastly, don't forget about cooling with 3 Rx 480 it could get very hot.

You can come and visit the other miners at https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/ or you can read specifically [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/comments/5lkjw0/rx_480_overclock_settings_hashrates_collaboration/)

Comment: Thank you very much! For detailed questions I will use the Subreddit.

Answer (score 2):

```
Is this CPU enough to power up to three AMD RX 480 GPU?
```

Yes, CPU doesn't matter for mining with GPUs. If you instead want to mine also with CPU, Intel i7 or AMD Ryzen processors would be better because it doesn't worth mining with a Celeron.

```
Is PCIe x1 enough for mining with GPUs?
```

Yes, PCIe x1 is enough for mining with GPUs. Also, in most cases, it prevents hardware incompatibilities.

```
And what power does an RX 480 use while mining?
```

Around 150W from the wall during the mining process, but you can push it down with BIOS mod and undervolting.

Answer (score 0):

This board (ASRock D1800M) does NOT support more than 1 GPU. When you connect the second card (via riser), it just hangs and does not boot, even post.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 GPUs on ASRock D1800M - RX 550 and RX 560 - both mining together.
I wanted to connect a third one (also RX 560) but the system recognizes only 2. 
The risers seem to be OK, I tried to switch the GPUs and try different combinations. Whenever I connect all 3, there is a probelm.
I wanted to mine with the 2 RX 560, the miner recognizes both, but only one is mining. 
The best option that works in my case on ASRock D1800M is 2 GPUs (RX 550 and RX 560)

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 GPUs on ASRock D1800M (2 pcs 1080Ti), works well.
I would attach a third card (1660) HiveOs not recognized all cards correctly. Two cards work seamlessly.